# Icon for sencha touch tabpanel tabs

Tags: html, sencha-touch, extjs

I have a tabpanel in sencha touch that looks something that below

```
Mobile.RootViewport = new Ext.TabPanel({
    fullscreen:'true',
    layout: 'card',
    tabBarDock: 'bottom',
    items: [Mobile.HomeViewport, Mobile.AboutViewport]
})
```

How do i have a icon for each of the tabs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an `iconCls` property to each of the `items` within your TabPanel (HomeViewport, AboutViewport, etc).

There are a handfull of icons compiled into the default theme, but there are *many* more in the *pictos* directory (found at `$touch/resources/themes/images/default/pictos/`). The iconCls name will be the same as the filename without the .png.

If you try and use an image that is not in the default theme you will just get a blank square, but you can add more by editing the theme's .scss file and adding line to include the image like:

```
@include pictos-iconmask('refresh5');  // includes pictos/refresh5.png
```

For help changing the theme see [An introduction to Theming Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/blog/an-introduction-to-theming-sencha-touch)