# How to add an Icon to a button

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm using Sencha Touch 2. I would like to use an Icon included in the Framework.
At the moment I'm using this code, but I have some glitch with the image being displayed, the transparency seems lost.

I would like to know if his is a proper way how to implement it thanks

```
items: [{
  xtype: 'button',
  icon: 'resources/themes/images/default/pictos/settings9.png',
  ui: 'normal',
  itemId: 'settingsButton',
  align: 'right'
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you refer to the answer to this question to learn how to use icons in tabbars :

[Icon for sencha touch tabpanel tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924336/icon-for-sencha-touch-tabpanel-tabs)

Hope this helps